# Unable to get ID token (Azure AD) using MSAL 1.0 for Android

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

In our Android app that uses MSAL 1.0 we can successfully sign-in to Azure AD. However, we cannot find a way to get ID token. Some examples on line show two ways to get ID token: `IAuthenticationResult.getIdToken()` and `IAccount.getClaims().get("id_token")`. Neither of the methods works for us. The former does not exist as a method in `IAuthenticationResult`. The latter always returns null.

I've looked at the source code that does the signing in and noticed that ID tokens are acquired and parsed into claims. However, it does not look like they are made available to library users in their raw formats.

I've verified during debugging that valid ID tokens are being acquired.

Our app needs to pass ID tokens to our back-end server.

Is there another way to access ID tokens using MSAL?

Btw, we do not have this problem on iOS and MSAL.

Comment: Why are you passing an id token to a back-end? It's only meant for your front-end. The back-end should only be used with an access token.

Comment: @juunas Pasing ID tokens to backend servers is quite acceptable. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth.

Comment: It's not meant for authorization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#using-the-id_token

Comment: @juunas We do not use ID tokens for authorizaiton. As per MS we use them to 'to validate that a user is who they claim to be'.  Regardless, do you know if there is a way to get ID token or access token using MSAL on Android?

Comment: You should be able to get an access token definitely, that's one of the main features of MSAL :) Haven't used the android version though :/

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed that the feature is not present in the Android version (although the id token is accessible as a string in the iOS version). It will be implemented in the future. For reference look here:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/850